# Is it the bug of jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have an area in which I want to add two buttons inside in. The code is pretty straight:

```
<div id="switcher"> 
 <div class="button" id="Sunday">Sunday</div>
 <div class="button" id="mic">mic</div>
 </div>
```

The demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/vBbeQ/

If we use the same CSS, but rewrite the code of the two elements in one line:

```
<div id="switcher"> 
<div class="button" id="Sunday">Sunday</div><div class="button" id="mic">mic</div>
</div>
```

The demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/vBbeQ/1/
It seems that there is a line break in the first case but jsfiddle can't recongize it.

Is it the bug of jsfiddle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because of the width of the `switcher` DIV.

When you write your code with a line break it will be printed a little 'whitespace' between the DIVs. And the width of the 2 `button` DIVs plus the 'whitespace', is bigger than the width of the `switcher` div.

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/aHwSL/)

Comment: I believe it counts as 1 space. You can tell by drag-selecting in the browser - you should see a space between the elements.

Comment: No matter how many "line breaks" between 2 DIVs, it will print just 1 whitespace.
You can find some ways to prevent the whitespace between the inline-block elements here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 3):

No, this is just how `display: inline-block;` works. It's sensitive to whitespace around the elements (just like `display: inline;`), so this:

```
<div id="switcher">
    <div class="button" id="Sunday">Sunday</div>
<div class="button" id="mic">mic</div>
</div>
```

Is different to this:

```
<div id="switcher">
    <div class="button" id="Sunday">Sunday</div><div class="button" id="mic">mic</div>
</div>
```

This effects rendering because browsers will render a space between the two `.button` elements. As a result they no longer fit on the same line.

There's loads more about inline-block at http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Answer (score 1):

It's not because they're on the same line, but because you have no whitespace between the two DIVs. Change the second one to:

```
<div class="button" id="Sunday">Sunday</div> <div class="button" id="mic">mic</div>
```

and it behaves just like the first one. This has nothing to do with jsfiddle, it's just the way HTML works: if there's no separator, it won't break the line.